# What is пройдитеськаде?

Tags: глаголы

How can I parse пройдитеськаде?

Please tell me what conjugation it is?

Answer (score 4):

ДЕ, частица. Разг.-сниж. Употр. для указания на то, что приводимые слова являются передачей чужой речи; дескать, мол. Да скажите: князь Гвидон шлёт царю-де свой поклон (Пушкин).

Частица КА разг. выражает смягчение или неформальность просьбы, приказа либо требование ускоренного выполнения ◆ Поезжай-ка ты в деревню!

Если частица, которая пишется через дефис, стоит после другой частицы, то дефис опускается, например: всё же таки, мы бы де так не поступили. Ср.: Такой-то де старик … и зол и подл (Пушкин); Кому же нибудь я должен это сказать! (Тургенев).

Правильное написание "пройдитесь-ка де".

Пример употребления: Простая, необразованная женщина рассказывает подруге о том, как водила своего 10-летнего сына на кастинг, где выбирали маьчика на роль в фильме: "И вот главный говорит моему Володе - пройдитесь-ка де от двери до окна, покажите нам себя."

Answer (score 3):

"Пройдитесь" is an imperative for "пройти(сь)" (to walk). (plural 2nd person)

The particle "-ка" is used with the imperative to soften it.

"Де" is somewhat archaic particle used to denote direct speech.

That is "[Он сказал вы] пройдитесь-ка де".